# Create a linearview on every activity to perfom action

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, ontouchlistener

I am trying to create view that sites underneath all others that will perform an action when 3 fingers are touched. These activities all have their own touches and swipes.

I have got this to kind of work by creating a class that extends linearlayout and intercepting touches. and adding this in xml.

But this is only being called when an item like button or view is a clickable or touchable surface and isn't becoming a touchable surface itself.

in

```
public class MyCatcher extends LinearLayout {

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        // multitouch!! - touch down
        int count = event.getPointerCount(); // Number of 'fingers' in this
        if (count > 3) {
                doThis(mContext);
        }
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}
```

And in xml

```
<packagename.MyCatcher
 ....>
      my normal layout
</packagename.MyCatcher>
```

So this code is working when an item that is touchable is touched but not becoming its own touch layer.

I have tried setontouchlister in the constructor with no luck.

Thanks for any help

**EXTRA: When setting the touchlistener via onAttach I can get it to catch touches but I can't use event.getPointerCount() like normal as it's returning 1. 
I'm worried this may take up lots of processing?/**

Comment: Is the onInterceptTouchEvent not even called once when you click on the view?

Comment: no only if I click on a view which is touchable. like a button.

Comment: The way i once implemented something similar was by letting onInterceptTouchEvent return true.
The view would then handle its onTouch event and when the view didn't need the touch event it would call dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent) on its child.

Answer (score 0):

```
onintercepttouchevent()
```

Is called only whenever a touch event is occured. ie; touch event occurs only when a view item like button,textbox,etc having onclicklistener enabled  is pressed . For your question you need to set the onclicklistener for the entire view.

Comment: I attempted to set the linearlayout.setonclicklistener(new.......   but this did not help it is still only interceppting touches from other views

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a Layout, create a normal View and add it to your existing layout so that it spans the whole screen and lays "above" all other views (in z-order). Now it should get all touch events prior to all other views. Your onTouch... implementation should make sure to pass all touch events along to the other views (except if you want e.g. buttons not to work under certain circumstances, then do not pass the events along).

Comment: This does not allow me to count the fingers, I always only get 1?

Comment: Ok, still going with this. if i return true rather then false. the pointers go up but I can't seem to then pass the touch on to the rest of my layout. i've tried dispatchTouchEvent(event); but it errors.

Comment: Have you tried to put your code into onTouchEvent instead of intercept...? That might help.

Comment: Good morning, Yes it is in a touch event but the pointers only go up if i return true, which means i can't touch anything behind. I have tried putting it at the back of the z order and this works to a point unless one of the pointers is on say a scroll view etc.

Comment: Hm, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas then :-(